# Node.js debug on VScode Remote WSL, VSC won't find the node binary

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed nodejs on wsl following this steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

Then debugging a helloworld example as shown here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial#_debugging-your-node-application

So I'm simply having in file `helloworld.js` at the root of the vscode workspace dir
containing:

```
var msg = 'Hello World';
console.log(msg);
```

with a breaking point on `console.log`

Then on debug tab I click "***create a launch.json file***"
which give me the default config:

```
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.js"
        }
```

But when I press `F5` the activity bar debug button makes a **blip** but nothing happens and no error message on any tab appears (integrated terminal, debug console, problems, output)

It's only when I specify to vscode where to get the node binary path by adding to the config:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "/home/user01/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/bin/node"
```

Then I get my code running and my breakpoint honored.

I thought it might be a problem of vscode not being able to find the path in a non-interactive shell so I tried as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52131394/usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-vscode-task) create a `/etc/profile.d/nvm-autoload.sh` with the following:

```
# Enable nvm if available
if [ -f ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ]; then
  source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
fi
```

But still not...

And the `runtimeExecutable` *fix* creates complications if I want to debug typescript files as it requires `tsc: build` as a `preLaunchTask`

I could run my typescript debugger along a `tsc -w` and getting ride of the `preLaunchTask` but I feel something is wrong somewhere and that's bugging me...

Answer (score 8):

The issue was due to the fact that I was starting Vscode from Windows *start menu* which don't set the environment variable properly.

To make it work I have to start vscode from wsl terminal.

```sh
cd ~/my/project
# if needed
nvm use
code .
```

then `launch.json` mentionned above works

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by installing the [WSL extension in VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl).

Then, restart VSCode by running the following command at your project root in a WSL Terminal :

```
code .
```

Node debugging should work properly.